# C# interface design guidelines, interfaces implementing interfaces

Tags: c#, interface

Are there design guidelines for the use of interfaces in the scenario below?

I *could* declare IDescription in DerivedClass or in the interface ISomeInterface or both. 3 choices, what guidelines would help me decide which is best.

```
public interface IDescription
{
    String Description { get; }
}

public interface ISomeInterface
{
    String Name { get; }
    String Description { get; }
}

public class DerivedClass : Base, ISomeInterface, IDescription
{
    public String Description { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: It all depends on the methodology you want to abide by.

Comment: If ISomeInterface is related to IDescription, then it should implement IDescription. (So if all ISomeInterface objects are always IDescription objects) If it just has a property which happens to have the same name then leave them separate.

Comment: It all depends,see interfaces as a contract that the class implementing must agree to honor,common functionality between potentialy unrelated classes.Now depending on what your goal is,you can leave it like that potentialy implementing one description property explicitly.Or erasing the description property from isomeinterface and deriving it from idescription....well it all depends..

Answer (score 5):

**It depends on the concrete interfaces and their logical relations**. There is no universal solution for every case. 2 options you mentioned will be right at some cirtumstances:

- If interfaces are not related (for example IDisposable and IEnumerable), then it's better that class implement two unrelated interfaces.
- If interfaces are related. For example IClientAPI and IAdminAPI, then admin interface may derive from client's interface, because administrator can do everything normal user can, plus some additional operations.

The case when interfaces derived and at the same time class implements both parent and children interface is rare if at all possible in well-written code. You can always avoid it.  I don't see any problems if you specify interface second time for class itself. At the same time there is no profit as well. So better don't do it.

**Important note:** Don't build inheritance hierarchy based on just matching property names - they can be same by coincidence. Always think if this is coincidence or fixed relation before creating base class or interface. Otherwise you'll end up with tons of interfaces like `IDescription`, `IName`, `IID`, etc that doesn't mean anything and only complicates the code.

Answer (score 1):

If the description property is meant to represent the same semantic object in both cases, I would have ISomeInterface implement IDescription for clarity. If they are not necessarily the same thing in your design, then no.

Answer (score 1):

Design guidelines basically depend on the requirement in this case. If you declare the *Description* in *ISomewhere*, then you will be forced to implement its other properties(which in this case is *Name*) even in the classes, which do not need the *Name* property.

On the other hand, if the Name and Description properties are required by all the classes where you will use *ISomewhere*, then it will be better to use it in single place *ISomeWhere*.

To get more precise answer, you need to analyze the where these interfaces will be used.

Comment: It's not good to build inheritance hierarchy based on property names used. Better analyze logical relations between entities. It will prevent you from creating inheritance hierarchy for some partial case so that it doesn't work for extention.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I have a scenario where I have two disparate classes using the same description which I wish to handle in one place through use of the IDescription interface.